# Convert fbx to 3ds using assimp

Tags: c++, assimp

I have found some kind of explanation about working with Asset-ImporterLib [here](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage/use_the_lib.html). Unfortunately it's very badly done and really important things are not explained at all. There is a piece of code which is really useless in my opinion, as it reads obj file and writes it back in the same format:

```
bool exporterTest() override {
    ::Assimp::Importer importer;
    ::Assimp::Exporter exporter;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(ASSIMP_TEST_MODELS_DIR "/OBJ/spider.obj", aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure);
    exporter.Export(scene, "obj", ASSIMP_TEST_MODELS_DIR "/OBJ/spider_out.obj");
    return true;
}
```

Can it be changed to read fbx file and write back as 3ds? Which import flags I have to use then? something like this:

```
exporterTest() override { 
::Assimp::Importer importer; 
::Assimp::Exporter exporter; 
const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile( "myModel.fbx", 0); 
exporter.Export(scene, "3ds", "myModel.3ds"); 
return true; 
}
```

Comment: According to the doc, this appears to be pretty straightforward. What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment nothing, stil triing to build the API with MINGW and without boost dependance. Which doc you mean?

Comment: The one you linked to. I suppose you can just try to load the fbx and the loader will figure the right loader to use based on the file extension. And the exporter says you just need to provide the right 3ds string to export it...

Comment: And what about that import flags like aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure?

Comment: Please test this out when you get there first, and come back to us with an actual issue you're facing.

Comment: What should I test out? Converting obj back to obj, like in that example, make no sence. So how to change that code so I can make some test? You mentioned doc, but unfortunatelly there is none.

Comment: So could this worck?
bool exporterTest() override {
    ::Assimp::Importer importer;
    ::Assimp::Exporter exporter;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile( "myModel.fbx", 0);
    exporter.Export(scene, "myModel.3ds");
    return true;
}

Comment: Yes, just supply the file name. I think internally, the importer will fetch the type of the file and use the appropriate importer function. For the export, you're missing a parameter that specifies the type (it's the [second parameter](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/master/API/API-Documentation.html#_CPPv4N6Assimp8Exporter6ExportEPK7aiScenePKcPKcjPK16ExportProperties)).

Comment: As for the import flags, you can take a look at [what's available](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=assimp+aiprocess+import+flags) and use what you need.

Comment: I don´t want to use any of that flags, thats why I wrote 0. Also you right forgot that pFormatId string, no description of what it can be.

Comment: Yeah, okay, 0 is the way the go then!

Comment: The types of the files allowed for the export is [listed here](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage/use_the_lib.html#exporting-models).

Comment: So pFormatId string should be "3ds", right? And the coresponding line: exporter.Export(scene, "3ds", "myModel.3ds");

Comment: That appears to be correct according to the doc I have read. I have no means to test it on my end.

Comment: Thanks, as soon I am able to build the API will test the code.

Comment: Sure! When you get it working, make sure you come back and share your findings with us :)

Comment: Don´t think I´ll be able to get it worcking, as it´s imposible to build assimp. But thanks for explanations.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Since it´s imposible to build assimp, just put all the content of assimp into my c++ project. After editing a huge number of include statements it seemd to work, but crashed at runtime. Looks like import of fbx file failed. I am geting folowing error string from importer: "OBJ: Invalid face indice".

Comment: Put a breakpoint where the error is reported and see the state of the stack at that point, that might help you figure out what is causing this in your OBJ.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Tried to import some other format like 3ds and glb, but got exactly the same error. The only format that seem to work is obj, but that´s really useles format

Comment: Then you might want to try what I suggested and see if there is something wrong there

Comment: @Vaillancourt Sorry, but have no idea what you exactly meaned.

Comment: Find the location in the code where it realizes that it can't process the model file, then put a breakpoint there and see why it thinks the file is not as expected.

Comment: @Vaillancourt The code is not mine so have no exact idea where it can go wrong.

Comment: Yeah, well it's part of your code now ;) You have the choice to debug it, or to do another project that doesn't involve assimp. Keep in mind that this lib seems well developed, so the error is likely on your side and not in their implementation.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Sorry, but saing assimp is well developed is a joke. I tried even older versions, but even after selecting an option to have the API without anoing boost dependancies it gives errors about mising boost. Without assimp my code make no sence, as I need to import 3D formats.

Comment: Use boost? As far as I remember, someone guided you through the process of building it the other day. I'm not able to offer more support than that.

Comment: @Vaillancourt The new version is free of boost, just wanted to show that the lib is not well developed. Also by project, I meand what is created by IDE. My code is more or les what you can see in the qestion, so it´s les then 10 lines of code.

Comment: @Vaillancourt that code for converting fbx to 3ds works.